# How to redirect to login page when not authorized in react-admin framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-admin

I have been building an admin panel using react-admin framework.
It worked well, but I couldn't make it redirect to login page when not authenticated.
I used authProvider.js for authentication.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please share your `authProvider.js` for us to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.reject();`
So in general, you can check if you are authenticated in `authProvider.js` file.

```js
// in src/authProvider.js

import { AUTH_LOGIN, AUTH_LOGOUT, AUTH_ERROR, AUTH_CHECK } from 'react-admin';

export default (type, params) => {

    if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
        // ...
    }
    if (type === AUTH_LOGOUT) {
        // ...
    }
    if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
        // ...
    }
    if (type === AUTH_CHECK) {
        return localStorage.getItem('token') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
    }
    return Promise.reject('Unknown method');
};
```

`Promise.reject()` redirect to login page in default.
If you want to redirect to other page, you can use `Promise.reject('/no-access')`.

Answer (score -1):

You must be using a Node API. So you can use a middle-ware everytime before every routing inside a admin oriented page, with a combination of JWT.

for example:

```
app.use('/admin/users',YOURMIDDLEWARE,(req,res)=>{
   //your work
})
```

And the middle-ware contains three params namely req,res and next. After you are done with the checking you can call next to pass it to the 'your work' part from the middleware.

[Check this blogPost](https://dev.to/dipakkr/implementing-authentication-in-nodejs-with-express-and-jwt-codelab-1-j5i)
Maybe TL;DR but that's the thing!